# How to enable a network adapter when there is no such field in the device manager?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I was trying to turn a windows 8.1 laptop into a wi-fi hotspot without Connectify and in the process decided to disable and re-enable Local Area Connection* 4 from Network Connections, but when I disabled it it disappeared completely. All the solutions point to the "network adapters" field in the device manager, but mine doesn't have such field, even after showing the hidden devices. Now even Connectify doesn't work.

Comment: If it is a cheap laptop, then the NIC might internally be connected via USB3 or another bus, where disabling the NIC makes it drop. Go to device manager and see, if you see it there (in a disabled state).

Comment: "  "My Device Manager" doesn't have such field, even after showing the hidden devices. "   That means the Network Adapter is not working (hardware failure or disconnected {less likely} ).  Get a USB Adapter (inexpensive) and install that.

Comment: @EugenRieck What is NIC? I think I found a "network adapters" field, but I'm not sure because my Windows is in Bulgarian and a direct translation of the field would be "network cards". There is a device called "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter", but it's already enabled. I have two hidden devices that are "Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3" and "RAS Async Adapter #2", but they can't be enabled. Every device that is visible is already enabled.

Comment: NIC is for "Network Interface Card" so you are on the right track. For some reason your Network card is not talking to your Operating system any longer - might easily be a hardware issue.